# how to find the most significant three digits of N to the power M?

Tags: number-theory

$N$ can be at most $10^{10}$ and $M$ can be at most $10^7$.
How can I find the first three digits of $N^M$ ?

Is there an easy way to find this like the process of finding last digit ?

Comment: If $N$ and $M$ are so small, you might as well just calculate $N^M$ rather than waste time thinking of a smarter method.

Comment: what if they are very large ?

Answer (score 3):

Use logarithms.

If $X = N^M$, compute $z = 3 + (\log_{10} X \mod 1)$ and then round $y = 10^z$ down to the next integer. This should work for $X \ge 10^3$ and should give a correct answer in IEEE arithmetic for the desired range of $N$ and $M$. For smaller X$, just compute it directly.

Comment: Is not $(\log_{10} X \mod 1)$  always zero? or you use mod with a different meaning? And $10^z$ is always a multiple of 10, that can't be most significant 3 digits of any $N^M$

Comment: $\log_{10} X \mod 1$ is the fractional part of $\log_{10} X$.

Comment: So, I suppose that in the place of `3` it can be any number between 1 and $M*\lceil \log_{10}X \rceil$